# Partial template specialization with auto template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have two enums

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum class E1 : unsigned int
{
    E11 = 1
};

enum class E2 : unsigned int
{
    E21 = 1
};
```

which have identical underlying values (`1`) in this case. Next, I have a class `C` which has two template parameters, an integer `j` and a value `i` with type `auto`.

```cpp
template<int j, auto i>
struct C
{ C() { std::cout << "none\n"; } };
```

I want to partially specialize this class for both `E1::E11` and `E2::E21` like this:

```cpp
template<int j>
struct C<j, E1::E11>
{ C() { std::cout << j << "E11\n"; } };

template<int j>
struct C<j, E2::E21>
{ C() { std::cout << j << "E21\n"; } };
```

And for completeness sake here is main that instantiates two objects:

```cpp
int main()
{
    C<0,E1::E11> e11;
    C<1,E2::E21> e21;
    return 0;
}
```

The code above works absolutely fine on gcc and icc as can be verified on [Godbolt (full code)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzFykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn4JdpgO6bX1BIVhkdFxrXUNTdlD3b3FpYMAlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1Caxbk4KBMSYrHvYJhoAgpdXjD7bm0wKCtvYXNsg214MqcAh6G2wQItxMAHYrNdttC3lwPnsACLbLigsEIvaQm7Xe4sR4GF5vMyfb6/PD/TCA4GozEwwnw2JIlHXcHo2KY24ETAsRIGTl7A6CbbaUjbJheIhA863I7ELwObZuakKiAzXYQ7ZHdAgFALAi7fb83ZmMwMASYEwAVjcDHMZgxaqRLIxoOunO5vPN%2B2BQql1xlcr1iv2wth2veKNiF2Z6rcKrVFg1BC1OvF%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%2BQlDUCjdHCwxjGsax9EimjIDmVBEmqGyAFpNURUwoMsLgwWoyo0vSFwGHcTxmn8SHJn6GIElyNIBFGFokhSFGGHhkoBlaUGOgELoRmhsYKiqTphh6YI%2BlxxHbCptG9COCYaamPG5gUWDlj0Y5MBWHg/wA8j9PAjhVGawivsIyRtmAZBkGRLgsKJCBIKsSwRVwQgSAQhIFVQdj6GIPWZiQlCZtIDDcJwgi7dw4j/w4MjSGA0Cxeo2jSHorQ5mYxAQF1RJxS4iAeL4/x8CIen%2BCO0RxDO2OLpUdR9L5gXeC26LEkWoWOEA12KLFzTxWDvVUCobYJalmW5YVpWVe2NXDd443TfNhjLet7D7ftkjnZF92qNsL2fYmp2zEH3gPe9i25issTwckIA%3D%3D)

But it fails with any other compiler (clang, msvc). With the following message

```
<source>:27:18: error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'C<0, E1::E11>'
    C<0,E1::E11> e11;
                 ^
<source>:18:8: note: partial specialization matches [with j = 0]
struct C<j, E1::E11>
       ^
<source>:22:8: note: partial specialization matches [with j = 0]
struct C<j, E2::E21>
```

It's kind of clear to me why this happens. The question that I can't seem to answer though is whether it is possible to solve this in a standard compatible way (if this is some gcc or icc feature) or if there's a workaround for the failing compilers (clang, msvc).

Btw. if I remove the `int j` template argument and just leave the `auto i` the code compiles with all compilers.

Thanks in advance,

Arno

Comment: It is clearly a clang/msvc bug, which seems to have issue with partial specialization.

Comment: I will file some bug reports then, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `auto` template argument can be replaced by

```
template<int j,typename T,T i>
struct C
{ C() { std::cout << "none\n"; } };
```

If you are fine with more typing you can explicitly specify the type of the enum:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class E1 : unsigned int
{
    E11 = 1
};

enum class E2 : unsigned int
{
    E21 = 1
};


template<int j,typename T,T i>
struct C
{ C() { std::cout << "none\n"; } };


template<int j>
struct C<j,E1, E1::E11>
{ C() { std::cout << j << "E11\n"; } };

template<int j>
struct C<j,E2, E2::E21>
{ C() { std::cout << j << "E21\n"; } };


int main()
{
    C<0,E1,E1::E11> e11;
    C<1,E2,E2::E21> e21;
    return 0;
}
```

And for less typing you can use a helper function:

```
template <int j,auto i>
auto make_C(){
    return C<j,decltype(i),i>();
}

int main()
{
    auto e11 = make_C<0,E1::E11>();
    auto e21 = make_C<1,E2::E21>();
}
```

... or a type trait:

```
template <int j,auto i>
struct C_helper {
    using type = C<j,decltype(i),i>;
};

int main()
{
    C_helper<0,E1::E11>::type e11;
    C_helper<1,E2::E21>::type e21;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue. Do you happen to know whether this is a compiler bug or a non-standard feature of gcc/icc?

Comment: @Azrael3000 I can only use intution which says: `auto` is not "any type" but must get deduced as either `E1` or `E2` in your example, hence nothing is ambiguous here, hence I guess it is a bug

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: especially when it works without `int j` in those compilers.

Answer (score 2):

msvc/clang seems to have issue with partial specialization in your cases :(

As workaround, you might split the parameter in 2 classes:

```
template <auto i>
struct EC
{
    template <int j>
    struct C
    {
        C() { std::cout << "none\n"; }
    };
};

template <>
struct EC<E1::E11>
{
    template <int j>
    struct C
    {
        C() { std::cout << j << "E11\n"; }
    };
};

// Same for E2::E21
```

and then

```
EC<E1::E11>::C<0> e11;
EC<E2::E21>::C<0> e21;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3zjcW13K7)